# Doctrine migration is not generating migration version for one particular entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using symfony and in that I am trying to generate new migration version with the following command:

```
app/console doctrine:migration:diff
```

it is genrating new migration file but there is a table in Entity directory called transaction for this particular table i am not able to generate migration or can say the table is not being created in database. Please help me generating migration / table by script only. I don't want to generate it manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem: migration wasn't getting generated for a specific entity.

After a while I found out it was because of my Doctrine Cache.
I cleared the cache pool and could generate my migration properly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to generate a migration file which will be get created in migration\ folder

Before migrating must Clear the cache

```
php app/console cache:clear

php app/console make:migration
```

Then hit this command to reflect your entity into the database

```
php app/console doctrine:migration:migrate
```

To check you current migration status and track hit this command

```
php app/console doctrine:migration:status
```

Install symfony CLI for ease from
https://symfony.com/download